# ¿Cómo puedo importar un archivo SQL utilizando la línea de comandos en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, línea-de-comandos

Tengo un archivo `.sql` con una exportación desde `phpMyAdmin`. Quiero importarlo a un servidor diferente utilizando la línea de comandos.

Tengo una instalación de **Windows Server 2016**. He colocado el archivo .sql en la ***unidad C***, y he probado este comando

```
MiBaseDeDato < fichero.sql
```

**No funciona**. **Me da errores de sintaxis**.

- ¿Cómo puedo importar este archivo sin problemas?
- ¿Necesito crear una base de datos primero?

Comment: Te falta anteponer el comando [`mysql`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html).

Comment: vale ya entiendo es ``mysql MiBaseDeDato < fichero.sql``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

## Parametros :

- **-u :** Usuario
- **-p :** Contraseña

Es mejor utilizar **la ruta completa del archivo SQL** fichero.sql.

Comment: muy bueno pero hay mas manera de realizarlo?´

Comment: Si usas workbench puedes importarlo desde ahí directamente sin tener que usar la linea de comandos.

Comment: ya pero debe ser atreves de lineo de comando

Answer (score 0):

Un uso común de mysqldump es para hacer una copia de seguridad de una base de datos completa :

```
MiBaseDeDato < fichero.sql
```

Pude volver a cargar mi archivo volcado en el servidor de la siguiente manera :

### Ubuntu :

```
MiBaseDeDato > fichero.sql
```

**Otras maneras que encontré :**

### Windows :

#### Sintaxis :

```
mysql -p -u [usuario] [base de datos] < fichero.sql
```

#### Ejemplo de uso :

```
cmd.exe /c "mysql -u Javi -p MiBaseDeDato < fichero.sql"
```

### Línea de comandos MySQL

```
mysql> use MiBaseDeDato;
mysql> source fichero.sql;
```